# How to change Background Colour for disabled TextFiled in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

How to change  **Background Colour** for **disabled** Text Filed in ASP.NET?

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomercode" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="  CUSTOMER CODE"  ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txtCustomerCode.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue; //change the color
```

Just use this. Hope it helps you.